# I need to print several labels, but no matter how many I put in, the printer always prints one

Tags: c#

It should be noted that I use a Zebra ZD230 printer and I also use a virtual printer, so we can ignore that it is the printer's problem (I think).
Actually, I have this code, I use the RawPrinterHelper class.
Any ideas or suggestions.

I leave the code here(It seems like a lot of code but adding an image to ZPL always generates a lot of code.):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static RawPrinterHelper;

namespace a
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s = "^XA^FX Top section with logo, name and address.^CF0,60^FO50,50^GB100,100,100^FS^FO75,75^FR^GB100,100,100^FS^FO93,93^GB40,40,40^FS^FO220,50^FDIntershipping, Inc.^FS^CF0,30^FO220,115^FD1000 Shipping Lane^FS^FO220,155^FDShelbyville TN 38102^FS^FO220,195^FDUnited States (USA)^FS^FO50,250^GB700,3,3^FS^FX Second section with recipient address and permit information.^CFA,30^FO50,300^FDJohn Doe^FS^FO50,340^FD100 Main Street^FS^FO50,380^FDSpringfield TN 39021^FS^FO50,420^FDUnited States (USA)^FS^CFA,15^FO600,300^GB150,150,3^FS^FO638,340^FDPermit^FS^FO638,390^FD123456^FS^FO50,500^GB700,3,3^FS^FX Third section with bar code.^BY5,2,270^FO100,550^BC^FD12345678^FS^FX Fourth section (the two boxes on the bottom).^FO50,900^GB700,250,3^FS^FO400,900^GB3,250,3^FS^CF0,40^FO100,960^FDCtr. X34B-1^FS^FO100,1010^FDREF1 F00B47^FS^FO100,1060^FDREF2 BL4H8^FS^CF0,190^FO470,955^FDCA^FS^XZ";        
            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
            pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
            if (DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this)) 
            {             
                RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, s);
            }
        }
        public static bool SendTextFileToPrinter(string szFileName, string printerName)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(szFileName, Encoding.Default))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(sr.ReadLine());
                }
            }

            return RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(printerName, sb.ToString());
        }
        private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be the driver.  Make sure you use the manufactures driver and not the generic Microsoft Driver.  Seen lots of cases of issues with Zerba Printing.

Comment: I just reinstalled and reinstalled the drivers from the Zebra site, nothing changed.

Comment: Do you have documentation?  You have a header row and should be able to also send a trailer row to end printing.

Comment: @jdweng At the moment I have not found any useful information from Zebra. Do you have any documents that might be useful?

Comment: You may need to update the firmware in the printer.  See : https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/code_128.htm and https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/zpl-command-information-and-details.html and https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/printers/desktop/ZD200d.html

Comment: @jdweng The problem is not in the ZPL, since it prints correctly, the problem is that I want to print several times that ZPL, it only prints once, that is the problem, and I tried even with EPL, and the result is the same, I think that maybe it is a problem with the RawPrinterHelper class, but I would not be sure of that.

Comment: It doesn't print correctly if you only get one output.

Comment: @jdweng  The problem was that to print several labels I need to add a loop.

Comment: Your code prints one label each time Button1 is clicked.  The title of code says "no matter how many I put in, the printer always prints one". The title implies that you clicked Button1 multiple times but the printer only printed one label.  If this is correct what would a loop accomplish?

Comment: What I meant was that in the "number of copies" section, if I put 2 or 3 copies, I might only print 1 label, sorry for not making it clear.